# JWT is not returning token when i pass Hashed password

Tags: laravel, hash, laravel-5, jwt

I am using `JWT` for generating tokens in Laravel 5.

When I am trying to get `JWT` token via user email and `hashed` password or `bcrypted` password it is returning me `false`. But when I am doing it without `hashed` password or `bcrypted` password, `JWT` is able to generate token for my application.

How can I make `JWT` to generate token when i am passing `hashed` or `bcrypted` passwords ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass hashed passwords to the default Auth class of Laravel because the Auth class hash your passwords before validating them against database. JWT is leveraging the Auth controller and hence it expects non hashed passwords because it is hashing them anyway

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the reply. I know about it. But i would like to know if there is any possible solution for this.